# Getting a model property of type "text" to use MEDIUMTEXT column dataType in mysql

Tags: mysql, strongloop

I have a loopback model with properties as follows:

```
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "fulltext": {
      "type": "text",
      "required": true
    }
  },
```

the `fulltext` property maps to a column of datatype in mysql when using automigration to setup the tables.

The following modification has no effect:

```
"fulltext": {
  "type": "text",
  "required": true,
  "mysql": {
      "dataType":"mediumtext" 
  }
}
```

is it possible to

1. configure the model.json to specify the mysql column datatype?
2. or otherwise have strongloop use a larger column datatype for a model property?

Answer (score 2):

I "solved" this in strongloop v5.0.0 by moving the `dataType`field to the base level of the property definition.

"fulltext": {
  "type": "text",
  "required": true,
  "dataType":"mediumtext" 
}

although I find this concerning as MEDIUMTEXT is mysql specific, this is the only way I can get the column to be added as mediumtext.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still looking for a solution without migrating mysql connector to 5.0.0 or above, use `dataType` inside of the property definition:

```
"fulltext": {
  "type": "text",
  "required": true,
  "dataType": "mediumtext"
}
```